# How to call a action from each loop while create a new element?

Tags: ember.js

I require to add a class name according to the index. as well I do have much other conditional events to add with each of the element. for that reason I would like to add a call back on element create.

how can i call a function from each iterator. I tried like this:

```
{{#each model as |flower index|}}
    <li class="(action 'setting()')">{{flower}}</li> //trying to call
{{/each}}
```

here is my controller:

```
actions:{
    setting:function(element, index){
        console.log(element, index); // i will add class name by condition
    }
  }
```

is it possible? or what is the correct way? especially i require to add different css classes according to the index value. ( for idea )

[Live Example](https://ember-twiddle.com/59280ed28b9293c8f34e8f9a91b41559?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

Comment: You can write helper.which will accept index arguments return the required class. You can use it like `<li class-{{settings index}}`

Comment: Checkout [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers). It's [`compute`](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#compute) helper allowes you to call an action from your template. `<li class="{{compute (action 'setting') index}}">{{flower}}</li>` would return the value of `setting(index)`.

Comment: In addition to my above comment: see [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/00ab501fd5573e56feae49305a355bea?openFiles=styles.app.css%2C)

Comment: Can you flesh out what your use-case is a bit? I'm suspicious that this is a mindset thing - and that maybe we can be more helpful with some specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. I would prefer to create a custom component which is used like this:

```
{{#each model as |flower index|}}
  {{flower-item flower=flower index=index}}
{{/each}}
```

Your custom component could look like this:

```
// Imports

export default Component.extend({
  // Inputs
  flower: null,
  index: 0,

  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['flowerClass'],

  flowerClass: computed('index', function() {
    return 'flower-' + get(this, 'index');
  })
});
```

See twiddle: [flower-item component](https://ember-twiddle.com/3240dd69f8805cf9ef86c88897be6ddd)

Comment: I am getting an error as `Uncaught Error: Compile Error: flower-item is not a helper` - can you please update my twiddle to reproduce your code?